# Pregmatch not matching correctly in php

Tags: php, regex, if-statement, preg-match

Having trouble understanding what's going on here. Comments within the code explain. Thanks in advance.  To make it easier to read some code bits are missing like the writing to the DB part. But the problem is isolated to these lines.

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == TRUE and 
preg_match("/^[\w ]+$/", $address_one) == TRUE and 
preg_match("((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,20})", $password) == TRUE) {
//When given a valid email/address/password the code successfully gets to this point and inserts into a DB

} else {
    //When it fails validation with an invalid email/password/address it drops in here
    //but then it doesn't change error code variable...
    $errorcode = "IHAVENOTCHANGED";
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == FALSE) {
            $errcode = " email,";
    }
    if (preg_match("/^[\w ]+$/", $address_one) == FALSE) {
            $errcode = " address line 1,";
    }
    if (preg_match("((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,20})", $password) == FALSE) {
            $errcode = " password,";
    }
    writetolog("LoginCreation", "Login failed due to invalid input: " . $errorcode . " - user: " . $email);
    echo "Invalid data for $errorcode please try again -- ADDRESS=$address_one -- EMAIL=$email -- PASS=$password";
```

}

Comment: You can't isolate it any further than this?

Comment: You seem to be missing delimiters in some of those regex...

Comment: I mean the last two lines are not pertinent information I suppose but all 3 if statements inside the else don't change the $errorcode

Comment: Put `die('IHAVENOTCHANGED')` at the top of the `else` clause. Does your code get to there?

Comment: When adding that above my comments within the else it does this:

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE"


With invalid input

Comment: `$errcode` is not the same as `$errorcode`.

Comment: Did you add a semicolon at the end? ;)

Comment: Why are you doing the same checks in the first `if` and then again in the `else` clause? Do them once, and then check whether `$errcode` has been changed to print the error. **Don't repeat yourself**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different variables `$errorcode` and `$errcode`, and are using the former in your `writetolog()` call. If you put these lines at the top of your code (and remove `$errorcode = "IHAVENOTCHANGED";`), PHP should complain about the use of an undefined variable:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

You also need to surround your regular expression patterns with delimiters - i.e. `/` characters, as mentioned by @elclanrs.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the problems already solved by the other answer, to validate form data consider separation of concerns. Think, you have fields that have to pass some rules, that's the premise. Here's a simple example. Free codez!

```
// Your rules can be regex or functions
$rules = [
  'text' => '/^[\w ]+$/',
  'pass' => '/((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,20}/',
  'email' => function($email) {
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
  }
];

function validate($value, $rule)
{
  $rule = $rules[$rule];

  // A function
  if (is_callable($rule)) {
    return call_user_func($rule, $value);
  }

  // A regex
  return preg_match($rule, $value);
}

// Usage:

// field => rule
// Use the `name` of your input in the markup
$fields = [
  'email' => 'email',
  'address' => 'text',
  'password' => 'pass'
];

// field => error
$errors = [
  'email' => 'Please enter a valid email',
  'address' => 'Please enter a valid address',
  'password' => 'Please enter a valid password'
];

// Get data from $_POST

$html = [];

foreach ($_POST as $field => $value) {
  // We confirm that this is a field we want to process
  if (isset($fields[$field])) {
    // Did it fail validation?
    if ( ! validate($value, $fields[$field])) {
      $html []= '<li class="error">'. $errors[$field] .'</li>';
    }
  }
}

// Print list of errors if any
if ( ! empty($html)) {
  echo '<ul id="errors">'. implode('', $html) .'</ul>'
}

exit;
```

Comment: Give it a try, just edited a couple things, it'll give you new ideas on how to organize your code for reusability.